# Pandas - Subtract two dataframes with left join instead of union / outer join?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, subtraction

I have two dataframes that contain the same column names, but mismatched row indices. I want to subtract them from each other, but keep the rows from the left one only. This is equivalent to a left-join operation, but instead of adding new columns to my dataframe, I want to substract the values from each other.

Here is an example - but I do not want to add the row `square` to my result!

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'angles': [0, 3, 4],
               'degrees': [360, 180, 360]},
              index=['circle', 'triangle', 'rectangle'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'angles': [1, 2, 3],
               'degrees': [370, 200, 20]},
              index=['square', 'triangle', 'rectangle'])

df1.sub(df2)
```

[image]

Pandas [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.subtract.html) are clear about what happens: If indices mismatch, "union" (effectively an outer join) will be done.

To me, it looks like there is an option `how` missing, where I can specify `left` instead of union.

Am I missing something? Is there another function that does what I want, or do I need to string commands together?

Answer (score 2):

While writing the code sample, I found a solution that seems to be working:

```
(df1-df2).loc[df1.index]
```